# Haskell Iterate over 2d list, filter, output 1d list

Tags: haskell

I thought I was smooth sailing in my Haskell studies, until...

I have a [[Int]]

```
tiles = [[1,0,0]
        ,[0,1,0]
        ,[0,1,0]
        ]
```

and a data type:

```
data Coord = Coord
    { x :: Int
    , y :: Int 
    } deriving (Eq)
```

Based on the input `tiles`, I've been trying to output a `[Coord]`, such that a `Coord` is only generated when the value of `tiles` is 1, and the `Coord` will store it's position in the 2d list:

```
blackBox :: [[Int]] -> [Coord]
blackBox tiles = <magic> 
-- given the above example I would expect:
-- [(Coord 0 0),(Coord 1 1),(Coord 1 2)]
```

I have tried things like first converting [[Int]] to a [Int], via:

```
foldTiles :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
foldTiles tiles = foldr (++) [] tiles
```

but after that I'm not really sure how to pass the indices along. I suppose if I could map over the "folded tiles", outputting a tuple (value, index), I could easily figure out the rest.

***update*** In case anyone's interested, I got it working and here is a demo of it (with source code and link to GitHub)! I will have to take more time to understand each of the answers as this is my first time programming a game using FP. Thanks a lot!

http://kennycason.com/posts/2013-10-10-haskell-sdl-gameboy-boxxle.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a place where list comprehensions shine.

```
blackBox tiles =
  [Coord x y                         -- generate a Coord pair
    | (y, row) <- enumerate tiles    -- for each row with its coordinate
    , (x, tile) <- enumerate row     -- for each tile in the row (with coordinate)
    , tile == 1]                     -- if the tile is 1
```

Or you could go for the equivalent `do` notation (since list is a monad), which requires importing `Control.Monad` (for `guard`.)

```
blackBox tiles = do
  (y, row) <- enumerate tiles    -- for each row with its coordinate
  (x, tile) <- enumerate row     -- for each tile in the row (with coordinate)
  guard (tile == 1)              -- as long as the tile is 1
  return (Coord x y)             -- return a coord pair
```

To aid with understanding, this latter function works like the following Python function.

```py
def black_box(tiles):
    for y, row in enumerate(tiles):
        for x, tile in enumerate(row):
            if tile == 1:
                 yield Coord(x, y)
```

`do` notation for the list monad is incredibly handy for processing lists, I think, so it's worth wrapping your head around!

---

In both of these examples I have used the definition

```
enumerate = zip [0..]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution (not guarantee that it's viable for `tiles` of size 10000x10000, that's something for you to check ;)

The approach is, as usual in Haskell, a top-down development. You think: what should `blackBox` do? For every row of `tiles` it should collect the `Coord`s of the tiles with `1` for that row, and concatenate them.

This gives you another function, `blackBoxRow`, for rows only. What should it do? Remove zeros from the row, and wrap the rest in `Coord`s, so there's `filter` and then `map`. Also you want to keep the row and column numbers, so you map tiles joined with their respective coordinates.

This gives you:

```
tiles :: [[Int]]
tiles = [[1,0,0]
        ,[0,1,0]
        ,[0,1,0]
        ]

data Coord = Coord {
    x :: Int
    ,y :: Int
} deriving (Eq, Show)

blackBox :: [[Int]] -> [Coord]
blackBox tiles2d = concat (map blackBoxRow (zip [0..] tiles2d))

blackBoxRow :: (Int, [Int]) -> [Coord]
blackBoxRow (row, tiles1d) = map toCoord $ filter pickOnes (zip [0..] tiles1d) where
    pickOnes (_, value) = value == 1
    toCoord (col, _) = Coord {x=col, y=row}


main = print $ blackBox tiles
```

Results in:

```
~> runhaskell t.hs
[Coord {x = 0, y = 0},Coord {x = 1, y = 1},Coord {x = 1, y = 2}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried this and it worked :) I will have to read through it more thoroughly (along with the other answers to understand it further)

Answer (score 2):

The way I see it, you could put your 2D list through a series of transformations.  The first one we'll need is one that can replace the `1` in your list with something more useful, such as its row:

```
assignRow :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
assignRow n xs = map (\x -> if x == 1 then n else x) xs
```

We can now use `zipWith` and `[1..]` to perform the first step:

```
assignRows :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
assignRows matrix = zipWith assignRow [1..] matrix
```

What's handy about this is that it'll work even if the matrix isn't square, and it terminates as soon as the matrix does.

Next we need to assign the column number, and here I'll do a few steps at once.  This makes the tuples of the coordinates, but there are invalid ones where `r == 0` (this is why I used `[1..]`, otherwise, you'll lose the first row), so we filter them out.  Next, we `uncurry Coord` to make a function that takes a tuple instead, and then we use flip on it, then map this thing over the list of tuples.

```
assignCol :: [Int] -> [Coord]
assignCol xs = map (uncurry (flip Coord)) $ filter (\(c, r) -> r /= 0) $ zip [1..] xs
```

And we can build our `assignCols`:

```
assignCols :: [[Int]] -> [Coord]
assignCols matrix = concatMap assignCol matrix
```

which allows us to build the final function

```
assignCoords :: [[Int]] -> [Coord]
assignCoords = assignCols . assignRows
```

You could compress this quite a bit with some eta reduction, too.

If you want 0-indexed coordinates, I'll leave you to modify this solution to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty solution:

```
import Data.Maybe (mapMaybe)

data Coord = Coord {
    x :: Int
    ,y :: Int
} deriving (Eq, Show)

blackBox :: [[Int]] -> [Coord]
blackBox = concatMap (\(y, xks) -> mapMaybe (toMaybeCoord y) xks)
    . zip [0..] . map (zip [0..])
    where
    toMaybeCoord :: Int -> (Int, Int) -> Maybe Coord
    toMaybeCoord y (x, k) = if k == 1
        then Just (Coord x y)
        else Nothing
```

The `zip`s pair the the tile values (which I am referring to as `k`) with the x and y coordinates (we are dealing with lists, so we have to add the indices if we need them). `mapMaybe` is convenient so that we can map (in order to construct the `Coords`) and filter (to remove the zero tiles) in a single step. `concatMap` also does two things here: it maps a function (the anonymous function within the parentheses) generating a list of lists and then flattens it. Be sure to check the types of the intermediate functions and results to get a clearer picture of the transformations.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is, using list comprehensions.

```
blackBox :: [[Integer]] -> [Coord]
blackBox ts = [Coord x y | (t,y) <- zip ts [0..], (e,x) <- zip t [0..], e == 1]
```

Comment: This will only pick the first "1" tile in each row. `elemIndex` is the culprit.

Comment: @duplode: May be I didn't get the question. So what should happen when there is a tile with multiple 1 i.e [1,1,1] .. should it lead to multiple Coord for each 1 ?

Comment: That seems to be the OP's intent - as in a game board, with the values being flags indicating whether a tile is occupied.

Comment: This seems very eloquent :)

Answer (score 0):

As long as we're collecting answers, here's another:

```
blackBox :: [[Int]] -> [Coord]
blackBox ts = map (uncurry Coord) xsAndYs
    where
        xsAndYs = concat $ zipWith applyYs [0..] x1s
        applyYs i = map (flip (,) i)
        x1s = map (map fst . filter ((==1) . snd)) xs
        xs = map (zip [0..]) ts
```

**Explanation:**

This assigns the `x` indexes within each row:

```
xs = map (zip [0..]) ts
```

Then I filter each row to keep only the elements with a `1`, and then I drop the `1` (since it's no longer useful):

```
x1s = map (map fst . filter ((==1) . snd)) xs
```

Which results in something of type `[[Int]]`, which are the rows with `x`s where `1`s used to be. Then I map the `y`s within each row, flipping the pairs so I'm left with `(x,y)` instead of `(y,x)`. As a final step, I flatten the rows into a single list, since I don't need to keep them separate anymore:

```
xsAndYs = concat $ zipWith applyYs [0..] x1s
applyYs i = map (flip (,) i)
```

Finally I convert each element by `map`ping `Coord` over it. `uncurry` is necessary because `Coord` doesn't take a tuple as argument.